# Cookie cutter for packaging Django app as a python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

There is a need of creating a Django project inside a python package and later package it as a python package.

Current thought : Can I use poetry-cookie cutter to create python package and django-cookie cutter for the project that is going to be used inside python package and merge them , so that the final result would be a python package.

Any suggestions on this ? Would help me move ahead.

Comment: same, did you find a solution?